# Angular - Upload file and render in Datatable after insert

Tags: angular

I have a problem when rendering a list of files to a grid.
The operation should be like this: When selecting the file and clicking ok, when closing the file selection dialog it should show the file name and size in a grid.
How do I do this using Agular?

html

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChangeInfo($event)"/>
```

TS

```
myFiles: File[] = [];
onFileChangeInfo(event: any): File[] {
    for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) { 
      this.myFiles.push(event.target.files[i]);
    }

    return this.myFiles;
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" multiple (change)="onFileChangeInfo($event)"/>

<ul *ngFor="let file of myFiles">
  <li>
    <p>Name: {{file.name}}</p>
    <p>Size: {{ file.size / 1024}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kplzzu?file=src/app/app.component.html`